# Create a route on symfony based on a json body

Tags: php, regex, symfony

My goal is to have a route that if the body which is a json string contains the string `"type":"pay"` to apply the route.

I tried this:

```
/*
 * @Route(
 *     path="/myfunction",
 *     condition="request.getContent() matches '/\\b\\"type\\":\\"pay\\"\\b/i'"
 * )
 */
```

But until now I get exception because when it finds the double quote `"` before type it thinks that the condition part should be over.

And I get exception like this:

`Caused by
 Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: [Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'type' at position 147`

Until now I tried the following

`condition="request.getContent() matches '/\\b"type":"pay"\\b/i'"`
`condition="request.getContent() matches '/\\b\"type\":\"pay\"\b/i'"`
`condition="request.getContent() matches '/\\b\\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\"pay\\\\\\\\"\\b/i'"`

According to the documentation http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/expression_language/syntax.html

I am using symfony 3.4

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea to me. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @fubar I know that there are other ways that I can workaround. But I am just wondering if I can do that. There are also various reasons which can't be explained here why this is my preferred solution if one exists. Just to give a hint we retrieve callbacks on the same endpoint and there are other functions that must be run depending on the type.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, is create an EventListener that listens to the `kernel.request`-event and has a priority that puts it before Symfony's `RouterListener::onKernelRequest()` for finding routes.

In this custom listener you can add an attribute to the request, which you can fill with the data from the request body. It could look something like this:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    // Maybe abort before reading content, if we don't expect a JSON-body

    $jsonEncodedContent = $request->getContent();

    // Decode JSON, validate

    $request->attributes->set('content_type', ...);
}
```

Then in your route you should be able to access this attribute instead of reading the json body, you can access this attribute:

```
condition="request.attributes.content_type == 'pay'"
```

The downside to this approach is, that your listener must run at the right point, which might cause some issues later on as it's hard to test for this, and this might be hard to find and understand for new developers on your project.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. The decoding of the JSON request payload could be handled by the `qandidate/symfony-json-request-transformer` package to keep things cleaner. And I think future understanding could easily be covered off with decent code commenting.